# What are AWS elasticache redis connection limits?

Tags: amazon-elasticache

We started an [AWS Elasticache instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/WhatIs.FirstTimeUser.html) on a [cache.t2.micro instance](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/).  How many connections will it accept?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html

```
maxclients  :   The maximum number of clients that can be connected at one time.
Default: 65000
Type: integer
Modifiable: No
```