# How to estimate the max number of connection an AWS ElasticCache Redis cluster can support?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

Is there any formula or "rule of thumb" I can apply to make an estimate of maximum number of connections a redis cluster hosted on AWS ElasticCache can support?

My cluster currently has 3 shards and 1 replica per shard. The node type is `cache.m4.xlarge`.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517578/how-many-total-connection-or-max-connections-are-available-in-redis-server) seems relevant for you, as it describes the Redis behavior.

But as you're mentioning AWS ElastiCache, max amount of connections seems to be up to 65 000 as referenced in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/973177/what-are-aws-elasticache-redis-connection-limits/973207). Answer contains link to AWS documentation.

Amount of connections from your web application (php, python, ruby, ...) to Redis server is what you're looking for, the size of the node is more about "how much you can store", not "how many connections you can handle".

So this might be your "rule of thumb": https://medium.com/appaloosa-store-engineering/you-should-revise-your-redis-max-connections-setting-8136f063c916